# Binance API: how to get the USD as the quote asset

Tags: python, api, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, binance

I'm wondering what the symbol is or if I am even able to get historical price data on BTC, ETH, etc. denominated in United States Dollars.

right now when if I'm making a call to client such as: 
Client.get_symbol_info('BTCUSD')
it returns nothing

Does anyone have any idea how to get this info?  Thanks!

Comment: That didn't answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can not make trades in Binance with dollars but instead with Tether(USDT) that is a cryptocurrency that is backed 1-to-1 with dollar.

To solve that use BTCUSDT
Change BTCUSD to BTCUSDT

Comment: It is worth noting that "backed 1-to-1 with dollar" is heavily disputed.

Comment: USDT is not USD

Comment: Two years ago that was the way to get the most accurate value on the Binance API from BTC to USD. I have not used the Binance API in a long time. If you know a better solution please write another answer. ( I didn't say USDT is USD. It is just that that was the only way to do it at the time)

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
        df =  pd.DataFrame(cliente.get_account()["balances"]) #CHEKEO MI SALDO
        df["free"] = df["free"].astype(float).round(4)
        saldoCrypto = df.query('asset == @baseAsset')[['free']]
        saldoCrypto = saldoCrypto["free"].values[0]

        saldoUSDT = df.query('asset == @quoteAsset')[['free']]
        saldoUSDT = saldoUSDT["free"].values[0]
        return  float(saldoCrypto),float(saldoUSDT)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please add more details by what steps are required to solve